# Openstack horizon dashboard url not found

Tags: openstack, devstack, horizon

I installed `devstack` on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 VM. I cannot get the default `dashboard` url to show. The url `http://<sever>/dashboard` shows 404 not found.

- I can see all the required ones are installed under:

  `suren@openstack-demo-vm:/opt/stack$ ls`

  `bin  cinder  data  devstack  devstack.subunit  glance  horizon  keystone  logs  neutron  nova  noVNC  requirements  tempest`
- Apache is running `service apache2 status` returns `Active: active (running)...`
- The default `http://<server>` loads the `Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page`

What am i missing?

Comment: Do you have horizon enabled in apache? Is the file ` /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/horizon.conf` present?

Comment: No. I see these "000-default.conf, glance-wsgi-api.conf, keystone-wsgi-admin.conf,  keystone-wsgi-public.conf,  nova-api-wsgi.conf,  nova-placement-api.conf" @vabada

Comment: Do you have `/etc/apache2/sites-available/horizon.conf`? If yes try to create a symbolic link: `ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/horizon.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/horizon.conf`, restart apache (`systemctl restart apache2` and try again

Comment: Not in `sites-available`, but i created `horizon.conf` from the example `http://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack-dev/devstack/tree/files/apache-horizon.template` and after i created a symbolic link, apache won't restart. If i remove the symbolic link, apache would restart.

Comment: My bad, after checking, `./stack.sh` did not completely run. It failed with an `exit 1`. I'm running it again to see it installs completely.

Comment: Just as a sidenote I have bad experiences running `.stack.sh` twice in the same machine, so if it fails for some reason, give it a try in a new VM